# Visual studio 2022 not showing color marks on scroll

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Since I have installed VS2022, it doesnt show me marks on scroll bar like "changed", "breakpoint" or "error". Does it have a configuration that I can turn it on?

[image: 2019x2922]

Comment: Did you import your settings from your previous version of VS into VS 2022? Do you have the [annotations option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-track-your-code-by-customizing-the-scrollbar?view=vs-2022#annotations) turned on?

Comment: @CodyGray I didnt know about importing setting. thanks! it solved :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also install Productivity Power Tools 2022 for this to have, it has a nice set of options aswell.